# rendering inside a backbone view

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

There is a backbone view for jobs and recipes in my application. 
The whiteboard contents of this view are rendered as raw text. I need to extract certain parts from the html and render the rest inside the view.
The view uses a html template which has the attribute.

The view render code is:

```
render: function () {
    this.$el.html(this.template(_.extend({guest: this.guest}, this.model.attributes)));
    var status = this.model.get('status');
    if (status == 'Running' || status == 'Completed') {
        var progressbar = new RecipeProgressBar({model: this.model});
        this.$('.recipe-status').append(progressbar.el);
    } else if (status == 'Cancelled' || status == 'Aborted') {
        $('<span/>')
            .addClass('label label-warning')
            .text(status)
            .appendTo(this.$('.recipe-status'));
    } else {
        this.$('.recipe-status').text(status);
    }
    if (this.guest)
        this.$el.addClass('guestrecipe');
    return this;
 }
```

The html template sample is:

```
<td class="recipe-metadata">
 <span class="recipe-whiteboard"><%- **whiteboard** %></span>
 <% if (!_.isEmpty(role) && role != "None" && role != "RECIPE_MEMBERS" && role != "STANDALONE") { %>
 <span class="recipe-role">
  Role: <%- role %>
 </span>
<% } %>
```

In the above code, 'whiteboard' is the attribute. 
Can I manipulate the attribute in the template itself? 
How can I render the whiteboard contents of the view without using a new attribute?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean *"In the above code, 'whiteboard' is the attribute"* - I don't see any `whiteboard` *attribute* in the template

Comment: Are you looking for something which could merge two objects into one?